# check dynamically type's variables android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a db, I open it and I extract query I need with a cursor. How can I check if variables I extract is int or string? Because i can't know which table I'm opening, everything is dynamic. So I can't use `cursor.getString()` or `cursor.getInt()`

EDIT

Sorry for my bad English, I'm italian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. This method works:

```
public boolean isInt(String s){
        boolean result=false;
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(s);
            result=true;
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getType(int)

Pass the column index to it. It should return you one of these

- FIELD_TYPE_NULL
- FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER
- FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT
- FIELD_TYPE_STRING
- FIELD_TYPE_BLOB

Comment: I can't use api superior than 8... There's another way?

Comment: If your API level is 8 then you have no choice but just try and catch exceptions

Comment: there isn't another way?? This is so bad... :( I have to do it for my job!